# How to add syntax coloring for AngularJS in eclipse mars 4.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, eclipse-plugin

Can someone help to get Eclipse highlight the syntax ( and code-completion ) for angularJS ?

Thanks .

Comment: The plugin is already installed. The syntax coloring is of a normal HTML, ignoring ng-xxx directives coloring and auto completion

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the AngularJS plugin from the marketplace? http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse